# C# Cefsharp Winforms doesnt read already saved cache

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

In my winforms, The browser executes a game through facebook. I have enabled to store cache in the localapplicationpath but for some reason it does not read that there is already cached files there. What I want is where once the user logs onto through Facebook, that the cache/cookies are stored and then the next time the user runs the application; the program first checks to see if there are stored cache/cookies; bypassing the need to re-enter the login credentials. What am I doing wrong or what can I do to where the user's login credentials are stored by the browser, and then read by the browser?
Here is my following running code:

```
        public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;

    public facebookbrowser()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeChromium();
    }

    private void facebookbrowser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.TopMost = true;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }


    public void InitializeChromium()
    {
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        settings.CachePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + @"\CEF";
        Cef.Initialize(settings);
        chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("apps.facebook.com/warcommander");
        this.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
        chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }

    private void facebookbrowser_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Cef.Shutdown();
        Application.Exit(); 
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a cache issue? Some sites block logins from embedded browsers, Facebook might be treating the browser differently. You can try changing the user agent as a test.